# Use filename from earlier gulp.src in gulp.rename() call

Tags: javascript, gulp, pipe, gulp-rename

I have a zip-file in a folder, I want to extract one of its (zipped) files and give it a filename pattern `source file basename + .xml` in folder `./sourcefiles_unpacked/`

```
./sourcefiles/test.zip
```

=>

```
./sourcefiles/test.zip
./sourcefiles_unpacked/test.xml
```

Unzipping & filtering works nicely with gulp-unzip, however I'm not sure how to access the filename from the gulp.src call.

```
gulp.task('unzip-filtered-rename', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.unzip_sourcefiles)
    // .pipe(debug())
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: notify.onError('unzip-filtered-rename error: <%= error.message %>')
    }))
    .pipe(changed(paths.excel_targetdir_local_glob, {
      extension: '.xml'
    }))
    .pipe(unzip({filter : function(entry){return minimatch(entry.path, "contents.xml")}}))
    .pipe(gulp.rename(function(path){       

        // ? What do I put here to rename each target file to 
        // ?   its originating zip file's basename?


    })) //   "==> test.xml",
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.sourcefiles_unpacked)) //   sourcefiles_unpacked: "./sourcefiles_unpacked/"
});
```

As soon as gulp.rename() is called the chunk has been renamed to its name as in the zipfile.

- How do I access or store the filepath of an earlier pipe for use in the rename function call?
- Is the gulp.dest properly configured if paths contains the glob "./sourcefiles_unpacked/"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const glob = require("glob");
const zipFiles = glob.sync('sourcefiles/*.zip');

gulp.task('unzip-filtered-rename', function (done) {

  zipFiles.forEach(function (zipFile) {

    const zipFileBase = path.parse(zipFile).name;

    return gulp.src(zipFile)
        // .pipe(debug())
        //   .pipe(plumber({
        //     errorHandler: notify.onError('unzip-filtered-rename error: <%= error.message %>')
        //   }))
        //   .pipe(changed(paths.excel_targetdir_local_glob, {
        //     extension: '.xml'
        //   }))
        //   .pipe(unzip({filter : function(entry){return minimatch(entry.path, "contents.xml")}}))
        .pipe(rename({
            basename: zipFileBase,
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./sourcefiles_unpacked")) //   sourcefiles_unpacked: "./sourcefiles_unpacked/"
    });
    done();
});
```

I commented out the other stuff you do just for testing purposes.  Running each file through a forEach or map allows you to set a variable at the beginning outside of the stream that will be available in the following stream.

Also see [How to unzip multiple files in the same folder with Gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57246332/how-to-unzip-multiple-files-in-the-same-folder-with-gulp) for more discussion on setting variables to be used in a stream.

Comment: This is great. Small follow-up: where would I find more on this , or where'd you learn how to make gulp work like this? Can't really get that far with standard documentation unfortunately, would love to learn.

Comment: Two things: SO itself and now with gulp v4 tasks can be set up as functions - and anything you could do in a javascript function you can do in a gulp task function.  They are more versatile than the `gulp.task` way (see https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/creating-tasks#creating-tasks) but as in my answer before you get to the stream part you can do any javascripty stuff you want.

Comment: I can see it can be extremely versatile, however handling async-ness with the through.obj still baffles me (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59154091/gulp-call-an-async-function-which-provides-its-own-callback-from-within-a-trans). For example: in your answer, I'd want to adjust it to be a function rather than a task (for use in pipe()). No idea on where to start, I'll write something up and post a new question; thanks for the step forward.